# How to integrate xBim in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, xbim

I have installed xBim using NuGet for unity, and it is working well until I try to use the GeometryEngine to create 3D shapes:

```
using (IfcStore model = IfcStore.Open(filename, null))
{
   var context = new Xbim3DModelContext(model);
   context.CreateContext();
}
```

context.CreateContext(); causes an error. At first I got:

FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Xbim.Geometry.Engine.dll' or one of its dependencies

Which is a bit strange since I did install the geometry engine in NuGet, but then I tried to compile the DLLs for the github project here:

https://github.com/xBimTeam/XbimGeometry

And copied them into the plugins folder. Now I do not get any error message, but Unity will crash to desktop on execution of context.CreateContext();

I have been searching online, but have been unable to find any workaround. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the answer (currently also trying to use xBim in Unity), but what I found looking throught the topics listed here:

https://github.com/xBimTeam/XbimGeometry/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=unity+

is that there is not direct solution for this. The workaround, mentioned in a couple of places, is to make the conversion from .ifc to .weBIM in an small external .NET support program. See this:

https://github.com/xBimTeam/XbimGeometry/issues/109

Hope this somewhat helps. If you have another solution I would like to hear it.